# How can use the value from the current cell in a Google Sheets function?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have the following function in a macro:

```
function payments(cell) {
  //return cell; //It works!
  return (spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue() + cell); //It doesn't work!
};
```

Then I called `payments(A1)` in `B1` cell.

I was expecting the value in `B1` to be updated when `A1` was modified, but `#ERROR!` is returned.

can you help me please to find out the right function instead of `getCurrentCell().getValue()`?

Comment: `payments(A1)` in `B1` with `return cell` works. for me. Which is the #ERROR! it is giving you?

Comment: payments(A1) in B1 with return cell also works for me. But with last return, the error is `Unknown function`.

Comment: The problem is it's entering in recursion.

Comment: Is recursion not what you wanted?

Comment: Yes it is, but it's n ot working properly. Like an infinite recursion I mean.

Comment: I tried also to  pass the current cell to as a parameter, also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the sum of the current cell and the content of `cell`, you need to rewrite you function as following:

```
function payments2(cell) {
  return (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue() + cell); 
};
```

**Important:** You have to run the function once manually in order to trigger authorization flow.

Comment: Did you save the function in the Apps Script editor and run it once manually? What is the value you currently have in the cell?

Comment: Yes, I did save the function in the Apps Script editor and ran it once manually. The value is `#ERROR!` When I put their the mouse I got `Unknown function`

Comment: I also tried this: `=IF(B1<>""; payments(A1;B1); 0)`

Comment: Please mind that the function I provided in the sample is called `payments2` -rename it if necessary.

Comment: I saw. I did not use your function name. I just  tested your return: `return (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue() + cell);` The name of the function doesn't matter!

Comment: The error you see is related to the fact that Google Sheets does not recognize your function. The possible reasons are a) You are not calling the function with the correct name or b) the script in which the function is defined is not bound to the spreadsheet on which you try to use it. You can doublecheck by going to Tools->Script Editor and see either the correct script shows.

Comment: Also, I see that you are calling `payments(A1;B1)` - you cannot do it because the function expects only one argument for `cell`, not two. Otherwise you have to rewrite it as `function payments2(cell1, cell2) {
  return (cell1 + cell2); 
};`

Comment: I know everything you wrote. I tried the function with one paramenter first, then with two. The problem isn't with the parameter (s), neither with function name. The only problem I have is I cannot use the value on the current cell with one paramenter or with two. I know this, when I use one parameter I put one parameter in the function definition and also in the function call and I do that for two parameters as well. That's not the problem. The function is recognized and works either with one paramenter or two. I repeat, the only problem is I cannot use the value on the current cell.

Comment: Indeed, you cannot use `currentCell`, this is why I suggested you to use instead `getActiveRange()` which is equivalent and works for me. If it does not work for you, I can have a look at your spreadsheet to see what the problem is.

Comment: Let me show you how I tested with `getActiveRange()`:

Comment: My sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/144vYwgzvE-unh7Dmxzst50PksSOGJuoymPhE5dppEEk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212875/discussion-between-ziganotschka-and-maf).